# Android - как удалить полученное смс

Tags: java, android, sms

Я получаю смс, как можно удалить полученое смс?

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "intet received " + intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
            Bundle dataBundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (dataBundle != null) {
                Object[] mypdu = (Object[]) dataBundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[mypdu.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < mypdu.length; i++) {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        String format = dataBundle.getString("format");
                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])mypdu[i], format);
                    } else {
                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) mypdu[i]);
                    }
                    msg = message[i].getMessageBody();
                    phoneNo = message[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Message: " + msg + "\nNumber: "+ phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный выше код не имеет отношения к сохранению СМС - это вы парсите СМС из уведомления. Если вы ловите бродкаст `SMS_RECEIVED` - то СМС к этому моменту уже сохранен в аппарате.

Удаление (впрочем, как и чтение/запись) СМС (и не только) в Андроид делается стандартным способом, через `ContentProvider`, вам нужен `ContentProvider` СМС сообщений, который система распознает через его `Uri` (что-то типа `content://sms/`). Конкретно в вашем случае:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), "_ID="+messageId, null);
```

Где `messageId` - идентификатор сообщения.

Comment: Да, в коде я получаю входящие смс, можно ли получить его id и удалить ? или надо отдельно получать смс (его id и тд) и удалять его как показали вы?

Comment: В вашем коде id сообщения получить нельзя. Его можно получить 2-мя путями: 1) Если вы сохраняете сами (при перехвате `SMS_DELIVERED`) 2) Или если вы читаете смс, то стандартными средствами запрашивая `query` с нужным `Uri` и читая колонку `_ID`